# How to replace a character from a specific position of the column in informatica

Tags: informatica

I am trying to replace a character in a column at particular position.

eg column is 12062016063000AM
So,I want to replace 6 with 7 at position 10;
O/P should be 12062016073000AM

I tried with replacechr() but it is replacing all the occurrence not at specific place.So,Please let me know any function or combination of function.

Answer (score 0):

Combination of concatenated mid(), left() and right() functions

Answer (score 0):

`SUBSTR(YourColumn,1,10) || '7' || SUBSTR(YourColumn,11,LENGTH(YourColumn))`

Or something close - I did not test the syntax.